# SQL Server 2012 SSMS Intellisense says "Invalid Column Name" in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to execute the following script on SSMS 2012 Express:

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, Quantity, 
    ItemPrice * Quantity AS PriceTotal, 
    DiscountAmount * Quantity AS DiscountTotal, 
    Quantity * (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) AS ItemTotal
FROM OrderItems
WHERE ItemTotal > 500
ORDER BY ItemTotal DESC
```

"Intellisense" says "Invalid Column Name" referring to "ItemTotal" in and ONLY in the WHERE clause. If I comment out or remove the WHERE clause, It works perfectly even though "ItemTotal" is also called in the ORDER BY clause.

Please help.

Many Thanks.

Comment: In Where clause you have to calculate `ItemTotal` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY` are evaluated at two different times during the execution :

- **WHERE** : this is evaluated first, to start building the "table" that your **SELECT** will display
- **ORDER BY** : this is evaluated once this "table" has been computed, to start ordering by the columns you mentioned

The aliases (ie. the names after **AS** clauses) are some kind of "renaming" of the columns of this "table" that will be displayed with your **SELECT**. It means they don't yet exist when the **WHERE** clause is computed.

Your **ORDER BY** happens after the `table` is built, so now the system knows what columns the aliases refer to.

To do what you want, you have to write :

```
SELECT ItemID, ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, Quantity, 
       ItemPrice * Quantity AS PriceTotal, 
       DiscountAmount * Quantity AS DiscountTotal, 
       Quantity * (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) AS ItemTotal
FROM OrderItems
WHERE Quantity * (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) > 500 --here SQL doesn't know what "ItemTotal" is...
ORDER BY ItemTotal DESC -- but at this stage it does understand !
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but I just assumed the SSMS 2012 would be a little better at picking that up. Thanks for clearing that up for me though! Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from 
            ( SELECT ItemID, 
                     ItemPrice,
                     DiscountAmount,
                     Quantity, 
                     ItemPrice * Quantity AS PriceTotal, 
                     DiscountAmount * Quantity AS DiscountTotal, 
                     Quantity * (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount) AS ItemTotal
              FROM OrderItems
             ) as t
         WHERE ItemTotal > 500 
         ORDER BY ItemTotal DESC
```

## [Sample Working Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b91e0/7)

Hope this helps

Happy Coding